# AVSpeechSynthesizer spoken text is being listened by the AVAudioSession record. How to ignore audio output from AVSpeechSynthesizer when recording

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

My startRecording function sets up an AVAudioSession for record, which is called on pressing a mic button.

Before pressing the mic I am using an AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak some text. If I press the record button before the AVSpeechSynthesizer speech ends that speech is being recorded by AVAudioSession.

How do I ignore the speech spoken by my AVSpeechSynthesizer and just record speech speaken by the user through a microphone?