# Make microphone ignore audio from AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sfspeechrecognizer

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260287/avspeechsynthesizer-spoken-text-is-being-listened-by-the-avaudiosession-record) question (which didn't receive an answer).

Context: I have a (swiftUI) view that has 2 buttons and a textfield. One button turns on the mic and uses SFSpeechrecognizer to turn speech into text (and fills the textfield). This is then sent to my server and my app receives a response, which is spoken through a AVSpeechSynthesizer. The mic is always on because the app is supposed to be conversational. Because of this, the spoken output is being captured by the mic.

Problem: I don't want to disable the mic when the response is spoken because I control my app through the microphone. **Is it possible to make the mic (SFSpeechrecognizer ) ignore speech spoken by AVSpeechSynthesizer?** Facetime does something similar by ignoring music played by your device.

My speech-to-text code is mostly modified of [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio).

text-to-speech snippet below:

```swift
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: serverResponse)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
utterance.rate = 0.1
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```